# Grant Access To Change Payment Methods To Azure Account

Tags: azure

I'm managing an Azure account for a client. Their credit card has expired on the account and I would like to delegate access to modify their payment methods to their accounting department without granting full admin/ownership access to the account.

I've granted them **Billing Reader** *AND* **Billing Administrator**, but when they navigate to Subscription > Billing > Payment Methods they only see this:

[image]

How do I grant access to update payment methods without full admin/ownership? or is this not possible?

Comment: I think that is still no possible. or?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isn't the Azure portal fun!

Per the [help docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-how-to-change-credit-card), only the **[Account Administrator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-subscription-transfer#whoisaa)** (the person who signed up for or bought the Azure subscription) can make changes to the billing methods.

The billing roles are used for accessing invoices rather than payment methods.

Comment: Yep not very helpful this, especially when you are creating subscriptions for clients and want them to have full access :(

Comment: I don't get what the "Billing Administrator" is for then, as granting that doesn't give access to invoices (those live on the subscription level and require "Billing Reader").

Comment: Also not helpful that a number of Microsoft articles explain how you can add Billing Account Owner/Contributor or Billing Profile Contributor roles to change payment methods. Yet I can't find this anywhere with my Azure account owner. It really seems like only the Account Administrator can change payment methods..

Comment: It's 2024 and I still don't see an option to Grant Access To Change Payment Methods To an Azure Account other than admin. Is it still the same?